# What are the drawbacks of a two-way polymorphic relationship in a Rail app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

I'm building a Rail 3.2 app that has some complex data relationships. I'm wondering what is the best way to structure the database.

The data I'm trying to model coud be compared to elements of Facebook.

For example, there are items that a user can create:

- comments
- photos
- posts
- status
- updates

Each of these items can belong to a

- user
- business
- location

So for example "User A took a photo at MacDonalds in Paris".

I want to show an activity stream on each user, business and location page.

The way I've thought of doing this involves a two way polymorphic relationship.

one for activity:

```
class ActivityFeed
  belongs_to :feedable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Comment | Photo | Status
  has_many :activity_feeds, :as => :feedable
end
```

and one for ownership

```
class ActivityOwner
  belongs_to :ownable, :polymorphic => true
end

class User | Business | Location
  has_many :activity_owners, :as => :ownable
end
```

Then activity_owner would belong to activity_feed, and activity_feed would have many activity_owners.

I hope that makes sense?

Is this a good way to tackle this case? Are there any performance issues I should be thinking about? Is there a better way?

A followup question: using this approach, is it possible to map the same model to a polymorphic relationship in multiple ways. For example a user could be an owner of a photo, and they could be a tagged user.

I'm stil trying to learn Rails, and I'm struggling to get my head around this issue. I'd really appreciate opinions, experience and ideas from others, as well as any pointers to useful information or guides.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.smartlogicsolutions.com/2008/06/13/ruby-on-rails-polymorphic-association-benchmarks/

it is old a little bit but still actuall

no big drawbacks if u r using right indexes, just less columns in your db

Comment: thanks yuri, thats really useful to know these performance figures. I think my concern is simply the size of these tables. For example every photo posted will have three records in the ActivityOwner table (user, business, location). If there are tagged users, or likes, or ... this number will be even greater. The ActivityOwner table will quickly become large, and even if polymorphic associations perform well, there will still be some overhead. Hence I'm wondering whether there is a better way to go?

Answer (score -1):

Interesting, Have a look at [Polymorphic Association (revised)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association-revised) by Ryan Bates. I think it will be a perfect approach to what you are trying to do. Nice and clean too

Comment: Hi vezu, I hadn't realized Ryan had updated his railscast. Uncanny timing, thanks for pointing it out. I suppose my question is really the next step. How best to combine different models (i Ryans case articles, events, photos) into a single collection so that they can be displayed on different owner models